# requireJS why does each define has to be in different file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using requireJS in my sample demo app. This is my code:

```
require({
    paths: {
        ToDoModel: '/Scripts/ToDoModel.min',
        ToDo: '/Scripts/ToDo.min',
        ToDoService: '/Scripts/ToDoService.min'
    }
}, ['ToDo'], function (ToDo) {

    ko.applyBindings(new ToDo(), $('#toDo')[0]);
}
);
```

I know I need some of the files as soon the app loads. Thus I want to combine ToDoModel, ToDo and ToDoService all into one file and yet `define` them as separate like this:

```
define('ToDoModel', [], function () {
    ToDoModel = function (data) {

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);


    }
    return ToDoModel;
});
```

All the moment all are in separate files as you can see in the paths attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS does not require that `define` calls be in different files. It's just that in development "one file, one module (i.e. one `define`)" works pretty well. In fact, the RequireJS optimizer ([`r.js`](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)) combines multiple `define` calls into one file during optimization. No problem there.

The setup you show in your question looks to me like a development setup. Normally, in development we have RequireJS load modules as separate files, not minified. (Your example suggest that you are loading midified code.) For deployment, we use `r.js` to minify and concatenate the various modules into *one* file that RequireJS loads.

Based on what you show in your question, if you did not use minified files you'd be able to use a configuration like this:

```
{
    baseUrl: "/Scripts"
}
```

and RequireJS would be able to find your individual modules on the basis of their names because they would not have `.min` in their names.

Comment: But if we have to concatenate every module into a single file and download whole file irrespective of other modules are required or not then what purpose does requireJS serve? I thought the whole purpose of RequireJS was to download JS / text template files automatically as and when need arises?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515679/requirejs-to-bundle-or-not-to-bundle/20518314#20518314), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272578/when-using-require-js-and-creating-a-single-file-using-r-js-do-we-still-get-the/21307947#21307947).